# How to prevent butter-based filling to spread out from rolled/knotted pastries?

Tags: baking, filling, rolls

When making Swedish cinnamon rolls (kanelbullar), or any similar rolled/knotted pastries, I have an issue with the filling oozing out of the pastry when baking it. Recipes are calling for a filling usually made with butter, sugar and spices. (The ratio being commonly 4 butter for 3 sugar, in weight + spices). When using that filling, I usually get a lot of leakage from the pastries, with a lot of the filling ending up on the baking tray.

Below, a picture illustrating the problem (brown filling on brown silicon mat is not the best, sorry):

[image: Picture of a knotted pastry with it's filling having leaked during cooking]

Are there solutions to that problem?

Comment: I'm mostly interested in solutions that would change the behaviour of the filling during baking, but open to other suggestions (such as using baking cups, or cooking them in a high walled tray close together) for the sake of the Q/A.

Comment: Have you tried refrigerating the buns before baking?

Comment: I didn't. I 'll try next time.

Comment: @GdD, once again, an answer in the comments.

Comment: I asked a question about the method @FuzzyChef.

Comment: @GdD, yeah, I'm just amused.  You have a track record.  ;-)

Comment: A lot of it is time @FuzzyChef, if I write an answer saying to refrigerate the pastry and it turns out they did it's not helpful. But, this morning is the first chance I've had to write an answer based on the response to my comment as I've had a lot going on.

Comment: @FuzzyChef some of us like to get clarity about what the actual problem is rather than just flood the answers with things that might or might not be useful.  There was a user on here that would do that all the time.  Because they were fast they got lots of upvotes, and when they were wrong (and some were spectacularly bad) they’d delete their answer before too many people downvoted it

Comment: @GdD don't be afraid to write an answer just because the OP might have tried the solution you have in mind. Our questions get read by many thousands of people, many of them are likely to be solving the same problem, and you can expect that there will be those who won't have tried it.

Comment: Chill, chill.  It's not a problem. LIke I said, I'm just amused the number of times recently you've made a comment that turned out to be the answer.

Answer (score 3):

The butter may not be coming out of just the filling, it could be coming out of the pastry itself as well (this is more common with laminated pastry like puff pastry). Either way your best solution is to refrigerate the pastries before baking. Butter melts at a relatively low temperature, about 34°C/94°F, so by the time you roll out your pastry and spread the filling the butter in both will be very soft and it will be melted in the oven in a very short time. If you refrigerate the pastries you are giving the pastry time to form a structure to contain the filling before it melts, and stabilizing the butter in the pastry itself.

If refrigeration doesn't work and you still get leaking then your filling has too much butter in it, try reducing the butter or adding a small amount of powdered sugar to it. Adding powdered meringue is a trick to stiffen butter cream icing which may work for a butter based filling as well, although it may add a flavor as well.